# Firebase - using TIMESTAMP as a priority and validating its not in the future

Tags: javascript, validation, firebase, jscript

I am using firebase.server.TIMESTAMP as a priority (as pre previous question [Firebase - 'pushWithPriority' - and validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561758/firebase-pushwithpriority-and-validation) )

```
var ref = window.lastref.child("Offers").push();
ref.setWithPriority(spaceof.data, Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,function (data) { $("body").prepend(data); }
```

This appears to work, setting the priority correctly.

However, I am adding a rule to ensure the timestamp is not set to a future time. Using this code:-

```
,"Offers" : {
        ".read" : "true"
        ,"$offerid" : {
          ".write" : "now >= newData.getPriority()"
```

This always fails. I have tried

```
".write": "true" // this works
```

and

```
".write" : "newData.getPriority()>=0" // this fails
```

and

```
".write" : "newData.getPriority()<0" // this fails
```

So I am starting to suspect the priority hasn't been resolved from the placeholder to a number yet?

Any suggestions??

Comment: So what is the value of the priority? What do you get when you use `typeof` on it? Is it a number or a string? My guess is that it's `null`

Comment: Once written to the database the priority is a number - miliseconds since the Unix Epoch. What it is at the time the rule is evaluated - I have no idea. Is there a mechanism to show/return a 'typeof' value from a rule execution?